# Access annotation at runtime

Tags: java, annotations

How can I access in `main` whether `check` in the `Sample` class is true or false?
What should I write in Main class?

```
    package annotation;

    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

    public @interface annotation {
        public String name() default "Jimmy";
        public boolean check() default false;
    }
```

---

```
    package annotation;

    @annotation(name = "Jack", check = false)

    public class Sample {

        public String str = "Hi";

        public void printHi(String str) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    package annotation;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Sample.class.getAnnotation(annotation.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29) to get your annotation instance, and call `check()` to get the check value:

```
System.out.println(Sample.class.getAnnotation(annotation.class).check());
```

Note that classes should start with an upper-case letter, and that naming an annotation "annotation" is quite confusing.