# Check if the calling method is annotated

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a use-case where the return behaviour of the callee method should change based on the annotation of the caller method.

Here is the situation:

```
@SomeAnnotation
public void caller(){
    return SomeOtherClass.caller(String arg);
}

// Returns X in this case
public class SomeOtherClass{

    public String callee(String arg){

        if(annotationIsPresent(SomeAnnotation.class))
            return "X";
        else
            return "Y";
    }
}
```

I went through some resources and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551287/see-java-annotations-on-calling-method).

I was thinking of using [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) to get the current invoker method.

I have no clue if this is feasible or is a correct design also. Could someone please comment on it?

Adding code:

Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {

}
```

Caller class

```
@SomeAnnotation
public class Caller {

    @SomeAnnotation
    public static void caller(){
        System.out.println(new Callee().callee());
    }
}
```

Callee

```
public class Callee {

    public String callee(){

        String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
        String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();

        try {
            Class<?> klass = Class.forName(className);
            Method method = klass.getMethod(methodName);

            if(klass.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class))
                System.out.println("HELLO");

            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class))
                System.out.println("HELLOW");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Caller.caller();
    }
}
```

Comment: You found some resource - did you try?

Comment: I am currently trying. I needed advice on the design approach. Is it the correct way to put things together?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672047/access-annotation-at-runtime#11672268

Comment: The problem differs in the regard that I have no clue what could be the name of the class of the caller method. Also, what could be the name of the caller method.

Comment: There's a fragrance of [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in the air, what are you trying to achieve? I would probably use a boolean like: `SomeOtherClass.callee(String arg, boolean annotationPresent);` to avoid the stacktrace hell

Comment: The caller method is client code. There could be multiple caller types of methods (like test cases). I want to add an annotation either to method (if there are standalone method which want these changes) or a class( if all methods inside that class want the changes).

Comment: http://www.java2novice.com/java-annotations/custom/

Comment: I really would advice against this.  Yes, you could look at the stacktrace (which is slow btw) and find out the caller, and it will work... until you run it on a less conventional JVM or some kind of JIT optimization occurs and the trace is no longer there.  It would be much better to supply this caller with a differently configured or different instance of the code instead.